# Hexadecimal chart for tertiary colors

Tags: math

Anyone know where I can get a chart of Hex numbers for the tertiary colors?

Yellow, yellow-orange, Orange, red-orange, red, red-violet, violet, blue-violet, blue, blue-green, green, yellow-green.

I need the EXACT values of yellow-orange, red-orange, red-violet, blue-violet, blue-green, and yellow-green. etc...

I am making a color-themed game.

I can't seem to find a chart that lists the middle colors in a name that I know.

Or does anyone know how to do the hex math for (anycolor * anycolor / 2)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The following URL lists a list of colors and their combinations. [HTML Color Codes](http://html-color-codes.com/)

For mathematical definition, I suggest you have to use decimal values to find color mixtures more easily. Please refer, [Math Ref](http://www.mathsisfun.com/hexadecimal-decimal-colors.html)